# jQuery .hover() in <td> content

Tags: jquery

i have tried to display the value in title on hover,
i faced the problem when i try to hover on a anchor tag in title it displayed some thing like this `<a href="http://blabla.com/1">one</a>` so that i have used the following code to overcome this..

```
 $('.table1 td, .table2 td').find("a, div, label")  
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).prop('title', $(this).html());
    });
```

Now, what i need means, when i hover other than `a, div, label` am not able to get any content  of `td` in `hover`, i need help.. anyone??

Comment: So why not bind handler directly to TDs? Or i'm missing something in your issue

Comment: you can directly add title attr in ur tag itself what is the issue there?

Comment: caz' when i bind directly, when i hover on anchor tag eg as one am getting this <a href="http://blabla.com/1">one</a> in title

Comment: Bind to TD and do element specific things in an if statement with `e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=='a'` or `$(e.target).is("a")`

Comment: @user2324085 like  SmokeyPHP said, then filter with event.target. BTW, using hover like that (in/out handler) looks wrong in your specific case. I'd use mouseenter instead

Comment: codesen, i need to have in multiple places so am used like this..

Comment: then you can go for some tooltip option

Comment: can u be more clear SmokyPHP

Comment: @user2324085 Quick example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVP3j/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this...

```
  $(".table1 td, .table2 td").hover(function() {
         $(this).prop('title', $.trim($(this).text()));
    });
```

Comment: Although it may also work, this solution will get every text inside the <td> and put it on the title property. If you need just the content from the <a>, you maybe find my solution more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question, you are getting the tag "" in your title and you don't want it, you just want the content of the link.

Have you tried the .text() instead the .html()?

You can also add the hover() event to the td and then look for the  content for the td's title.

```
$('.table1 td, .table2 td').hover(function() {
    $(this).prop('title', $(this).find("a").text());
});
```

**Edit:** Here http://jsfiddle.net/9HBr7/ you can find the example running

Comment: This sounds the same as i mentioned above

Comment: It is not the same. As I have explained, it puts the hover function and the title at the TD, so it will fire every time the mouse hover over any element of the TD. However, the title content will be get from Text of the inner link.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo Cardoso

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue

```
$("table td *").hover(function(e) {
   $(this).prop('title', $(this).html());
});
```